# proc_open zipcloak doesn't work

Tags: php, shell, zip, php-ziparchive

I have a problem with setting password for zip files. The server runs php 5.5 and the `ZipArchive::setPassword()` is only supported by php 5.6. My boss doesn't want to upgrade to php 5.6 yet so I have to bypass setting passwords for auto generated zip files by using `proc_open()` and the `zipcloak` command. However it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
    /**
     * filename = the name of the zip file you want to encrypt containing the file path as well 
     **/
    public function encryptZip($filename, $password){
        $command = 'zipcloak ' . $filename;
        $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
        2 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stderr
        );

    // Opening the process
        $process = proc_open($command, $descriptorspec, $pipes);
        if(is_resource($process))
        {
        fwrite($pipes[0], $password."\n".$password);
        fclose($pipes[0]);
        fclose($pipes[1]);
        fclose($pipes[2]);
        // Closing the process
        $return_value = proc_close($process); // This prints 12
        }
    }
}
// end of class
$zip = new DZip();
$zip->encryptZip('path/to/zip.zip', '12345');
```

The zipcloak command asks for the password twice, that's why I use the `fwrite($pipes[0], $password."\n".$password);`. I have searched the web for hours for easier solutions, I have found `zip -P [password]` too but it only creates new files and I create my zip files with `ZipArchive` because the folder structure of the zip requires it. Any help? I don't get any error messages. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you on Windows by chance?

Answer (score 2):

So, I found a solution by myself. I created a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
command -v zipcloak && echo "exist" || exit -1;
command -v expect && echo "exist" || exit -1;
MYPWD="[password]"
expect -c ' 
spawn zipcloak [filename]
expect "*Enter password*" 
sleep 0.1
send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
sleep 0.1
expect "*Verify password*" 
sleep 0.1
send  "'"$MYPWD"'\r"
sleep 0.1
'
```

I can simply use exec from my php code:

```
public function encryptZip($filename, $password, $bashdir){
    $bash = str_replace('[filename]', $filename, (str_replace('[password]', $password, file_get_contents($bashdir))));
    exec($bash);
}
```

It works only on linux servers, where `expect` and `zipcloak` are installed, but that's not a problem for me. We run linux and both tools are installed.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: compile the zip-3.0 sources and use the undocumented

```
-DPASSWD_FROM_STDIN
```

option in the unix/Makefile. This will allow you to feed a password (repeated twice) from stdin.

```
CFLAGS_NOOPT = -I. -DUNIX $(LOCAL_ZIP) -DPASSWD_FROM_STDIN
```